# FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams succeeds but error gets returned

Tags: ios, facebook

I attempted to use `[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams]` to post a story to the facebook. It works in that I see the post but I get a strange error back in the `FBSDKLog`.

```
FBSDKLog: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x26958c0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            message = "(#100) The parameter 'custom_events' or 'custom_events_file' is required for the 'CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS' activity";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
```

What does it mean? I tried looking for `custom_events_file` and `custom_events` to no avail. This is using iOS facebook SDK 3.5

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find any resolution?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remove this error by disabling "Install Insights" & "Mobile SDK Insights" in the app console within Facebook.  It appears that Custom Events are related to App tracking within Facebook insights.