# ios FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink callback returns Error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying open facebook share dialog . it was previously working last month on iphone 5s.
but now it is not opening any of my facebook activities. like facebook share or facebook invite.

Please note this code is working perfectly on iphone 5 , ipad , iphone 4s.

**Only not working in iphone 5s or later devices.**

I m using this code for facebook share.

```
FBAppCall *appCall= nil;
appCall = [FBDialogs 
   presentShareDialogWithLink : urlToShare
                         name : @"hello world asda asdas"
                      caption : nil
                  description : @"asdasd asdas"
                      picture : [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSjwkxnvc10dDUqi4dpzI2ovHpdAHwTvYLhi-TCjBSfhkUJAM8Qng"]
                  clientState : nil
                      handler : ^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                    } else {
                                        //NSLog(@"Success!");
                                    }
                                }
];
```

This question is quite duplicate of [presentsharedialogwithparams-posts-to-fb-wall-but-callback-handler-results-say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259829/presentsharedialogwithparams-posts-to-fb-wall-but-callback-handler-results-say)
but answers to that question also not helps.

**NSLog shows this error:**

> Error: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=11
>
> "The user navigated away from the Facebook app prior to completing this AppCall. 
>    
> This AppCall is now cancelled and needs to be retried to get a successful completion" 
>    
> UserInfo=0x14dbf2a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The user navigated away from the 
>      Facebook app prior to completing this AppCall. 
>   This AppCall is now cancelled and needs to be retried to get a successful completion}

**Moreover i had tried sample from [FBShareSample](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos) but its not working in iphone 5s, but its working in other devices.**

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error too and what fixed it was that FacebookDisplayName in the plist needs to be EXACTLY the same as in the Facebook developer console settings for the app.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are missing some steps mentioned in documentation.
Please refer to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.2-to-3.5/)

Comment: as I mentioned , my code is working perfectly in other devices.  please mention what step , am i missing. i dont understand if i missed something then my code should't be working on devices also.